# Failure in nested model validation via JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, dart

I created a method to validate via JSON a nested model, but it is giving me the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes:  table_fields):
```

This is a error that I saw in other questions here in SO, but none of them helped to solve my problem. I have no clue what to do, following my methods and models:

**Table (Model):**

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :x, :y, :name, :table_fields_attributes

  validates :name, :presence => :true

  has_many :table_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :table_fields, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Table Fields (Model)**

```
class TableField < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foreign_key, :name, :primary_key, :data_type, :table_id
  belongs_to :table

  validates :name, :presence => :true
end
```

**validate method in table_controller**

```
  # POST /table.json/validate
  def validate
    @table = Table.new(params[:table])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @table.valid? == false
        format.json { render json: @table.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      else
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end
```

**part of routes.rb**

```
  resources :tables do
    resources :table_fields
  end
  match "/table.json/validate" => "tables#validate"
```

**JSON I'm sending**

```
{"table":{"y":5,"name":"","x":5,"table_fields":[{"table_field":{"data_type":"CHAR","primary_key":true,"foreign_key":false,"name":""}}]}}
```

**The code involving  the HttpRequest ([Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/))**

```
  void validate(Table table)
  {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR
    String url = "/table.json/validate";
    req.open("POST", url); // Use POST http method to send data in the next call]
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String tableJson = table.toJson();
    req.send(tableJson); // kick off the request to the server
  }
```

**The class Table**

```
class Table{
  int tableId;
  List<TableField> tableFields;
  String name;

  num x;
  num y;
  num width;
  num height;

  Table(String name, num x, num y, List<TableField> tableFields)  {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.tableFields = tableFields;

  }


  toJson()
  {
    Map map = new Map();
    map["table"] = new Map();
    map["table"]["name"] = this.name;
    map["table"]["x"] = this.x;
    map["table"]["y"] = this.y;

    List<Map> mappedFields = new List<Map>();
    Map fieldMap = new Map();
    fieldMap["table_field"] = new Map();

    //Testing with 1 entry only
    TableField tableField = tableFields[0];

     fieldMap["table_field"]["name"] = tableField.name;
     fieldMap["table_field"]["data_type"] = tableField.dataType;
     fieldMap["table_field"]["primary_key"] = tableField.primaryKey;
     fieldMap["table_field"]["foreign_key"] = tableField.foreignKey;
     mappedFields.add(fieldMap);


    map["table"]["table_fields_attributes"] = mappedFields;

    return stringify(map);


  }


}
```

**Full error stack**

```
Started POST "/table.json/validate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-22 15:17:00 -0300
Processing by TablesController#validate as */*
  Parameters: {"table"=>{"y"=>5, "name"=>"", "x"=>5, "table_fields"=>[{"table_field"=>{"data_type"=>"444", "primary_key"=>true, "foreign_key"=>false, "name"=>""}}]}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2260ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: table_fields):
  app/controllers/tables_controller.rb:88:in `new'
  app/controllers/tables_controller.rb:88:in `validate'
```

Comment: how are you sending the JSON string? I mean, are you building it manually in javascript method or serializing the form?

Comment: I updated the question with that info, I'm using a HttpRequest and sending as I showed in the question.

Comment: ok then it seems to be problem in `fields_for` in your view file, it is suppose to be `table_fields_attributes` instead of `table_fields`. May be adding the view code can help. Sorry for not adding this part in first comment :)

Comment: I don't have a view file, I'm using Ruby on Rails as a back-end system. My front-end system is recieving a map containing the errors or no_content if everything is OK.

Comment: Ok.. you're using `String tableJson = table.toJson()` to get the JSON content. Where are you geetting this `table` from? You might need to replace `table_fields` with `table_fields_attributes` in that table.

Comment: You mean change the JSON to something like:
 {"table":{"y":5,"table_fields_attributes":[{"table_field":{"data_type":"CHAR","primary_key":true,"foreign_key":false,"name":""}}],"name":"","x":5}} ?
Changing that made me receive a different error: " (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: table_field):" (notice it's not table_fields, but table_field now).

If it helps, I also put the Table class so you can know where the Table comes from.

Comment: Change the JSON to look like `{"table"=>{"y"=>5, "name"=>"", "x"=>5, "table_fields"=>{"0"=>{"data_type"=>"444", "primary_key"=>true, "foreign_key"=>false, "name"=>""}, "1" => {"data_type"=>"somedata", "primary_key"=>true, "foreign_key"=>false, "name"=>"somedat"}}}}`. Notice, I have removed **[]** and you do not have to pass **table_field**, instead you need to pass different indices for passing multiple records at a time. **And you would also need to skip the crsf varification by adding `protect_from_forgery :except => :validate` in your ApplicationController or `TableController`.

Comment: @SybariteManoj I appreciate your help, thanks :). Unfortunately, that  didn't work also. (I'll check the protect_from_forgery in another moment, but thanks for the tip).

Comment: I tried changing `:table_fields_attributes` to `:table_fields`, and executing with your JSON, I received: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (TableField(#24627912) expected, got Array(#3271836)):`

Answer (score 1):

Either change the attr accessible declaration to use table_fields instead of table_fields_attributes or change the json to send the table_fields_attributes element instead of table_fields

```
attr_accessible :x, :y, :name, :table_fields_attributes
```

or

```
{"table":{"y":5,"name":"","x":5,"table_fields_attributes":[{"table_field":{"data_type":"CHAR","primary_key":true,"foreign_key":false,"name":""}}]}}
```

Either should work

Comment: Thank you, actually this answer helped me to find a way to fix, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way. I changed attr_acessible to `attr_accessible :x, :y, :name, :table_fields_attributes, :table_fields` , is it okay to do this?

Comment: @EduardoCopat That's fine and it won't cause any problems but it would be better to change the json if only so that you get more familiar with the way json works